# Writing one character at a time in a C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, console

I'm not sure how to explain this...

Basically I want to be able to write lines of text in a console window like old RPGs used to write their dialogue, one character at a time. An example here from the game Pokemon Mystery Dungeon(Contains spoilers btw): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i29juf2e92c

Basically like how the dialogue is displayed.

Edit: Should also mention, I'm going to be reading the text from a file, and I'd like to write the text in that file one character at a time.

Comment: try some tutorials fisrst - http://www.dotnetperls.com/console , http://www.dotnetperls.com/console-readline

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. 
Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? 
Show your effort first so people might show theirs. 
Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start..

Comment: @KCdod: I don't see how `Console.ReadLine` is relevant, and the `Console` tutorial only talks about `Console.WriteLine`, not `Console.Write`

Comment: Where is your effort ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just use [`Console.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/testw4x7(v=vs.110).aspx) to print a single character at a time without the line break that `WriteLine` would provide, and call `Thread.Sleep` to pause briefly between characters. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "This will be printed one character at a time";
        foreach (char c in text)
        {
            Console.Write(c);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should have explained, I am going to be reading and writing the text from a file so this probably won't do. Sorry.

Comment: @Revan114: In what way? Just because I've hard-coded it in my sample app doesn't mean it has to be done that way. The `foreach` loop is the bit that prints it out - and that doesn't care how the data got into the `text` variable. If you *also* need to know how to read text from a file, you should do some research to try to work out how to do that for yourself, and ask a separate question if you get stuck. It's very important that you learn to split a big task into little tasks - you asked about printing a message one character at a time, so that's what my answer does.

Comment: Then give a better Problem Specification

Comment: Oh I think I get it now. Thanks. Will mark your answer in 6 minutes.